# Raw extraction of frames from a movie

Tags: java, image, scala, image-processing, ffmpeg

I would like to extract images from a grayscale [mj2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG_2000) movie. Each pixel is encoded using 16 bits. Since this is a technical movie, I need to extract the value at each pixel without processing, as those values linearly map to a physical quantity (a heatmap from an infrared camera). I am using Scala, and I do not find any suitable solution for a direct extraction (either in Scala or in Java, but I am a beginner). Therefore I intend to use ffmpeg to extract individual frames on the disk, then load them as BufferedImage in Scala and process them.

Is this a good approach ? Which format should I use to avoid any transformation in the data ? I want each extracted frame to ba as "raw" as possible ? Is it possible to directly output a csv containing the aforementionned values ?

Comment: Can you post a short sample? Preferably one with known values (at some pixels).

Comment: The data is covered by a non disclosure agreement unfortunately.

Comment: Can you generate synthetic data of the same format?

Comment: I do not know how the data was generated, I can not recreate it... I only know that the file is valid and not corrupted because I can open the mj2 file in mplayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple option might be to use an image processing library, like OpenCV. It provides utilities to open a wide range of files and extract the information required.

Comment: Thsi is more like a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: Well, using ffmpeg is not a good approach as it is not simple, OpenCV allows for decoding of the images as matrices (a pretty much "raw" format), and outputing a csv would be trivial. What more would you expect from an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer, without looking at a sample, is to use the segment muxer

```
ffmpeg -i in.mj2 -f segment -segment_time 0.01 -map 0 -segment_format data frame%d.raw
```

But since the input codec is JPEG-2000, you may be able to run

```
ffmpeg -i in.mj2 -c copy frame%d.jp2
```

Comment: I have read that raw formats vary from camera to camera, what is the format of the raw files from the first command ?

Comment: The second command generates jp2 files that I can not open. However, whan I apply it, I got the message here: http://pastebin.com/83bhdyyW . In particular, the Stream #0:0: Video is different in the input (l.20) and in the ouput (l.32). Is the the reason why the generated jp2 are unreadable ?